# $(window).scroll(function () { stopping ajax from firing

Tags: javascript, ajax

For some reason the  `$(window).scroll(function () {`  is stopping ajax from firing.

I've done a few tests. I completely removed my CSS fileto remove any overflows or heights set in the html,body, as this was a common thing that was stopping it on the net. 
when I remove just the line `$(window).scroll(function () {`my ajax fires on page load but then if I want to scroll for new content i can't.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 100) {
            flag = true;
            first = $('#first').val();
            limit = $('#limit').val();
            no_data = true;
            if (flag && no_data) {
                flag = false;
                $('#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "commentedoncontent.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    method: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    data: {
                        start: first,
                        limit: limit
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        flag = true;
                        $('#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                        if (data.count > 0) {
                            first = parseInt($('#first').val());
                            limit = parseInt($('#limit').val());
                            $('#first').val(first + limit);
                            $.each(data.posts, function(i, response) {
                                //post content here
                            });
                        } else {
                            alert('No more data to show');
                            no_data = false;
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(xhr.status);
                        flag = true;
                        no_data = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So `$(window).scroll` is not killing ajax, it isn't firiing its callback?

Comment: No it is killing the ajax. Its not firing at all when I load the page unless i remove that tiny bit of code that I need.

Comment: So if you replace all the code in `$(window).scroll`'s callback with `alert('test')`, do you get the alert box when you scroll?

Comment: Try having the ajax call on a `setTimeout` instead of being called from directly in the scroll callback.

Comment: to see if the ajax killed/cut or not, just look at the network inspector while executing the ajax. if there is no request detected, then the ajax is not killed, but it's canceled or not executed.

Comment: Okay guys, it would seem that my page didn't have the standard browser overflow-y on page load because until the scroll is moved...the json content isn't received. So I need to get the content on page load and then scroll for any new content.